# Limit of matrix to a power and diagonalized matrix to a power give different results

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have the following problem. I wish to find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \psi M^n 1
$$
where
$$
\psi = \begin{bmatrix} 1/4 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
and 
$$
M=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \left( 1-\frac{L}{n} \right)^2 
        & 2 \left(\frac{L}{n} \right) \left(1-\frac{L}{n}\right) \\
        \left(\frac{L}{n} \right) \left(1-\frac{L}{n}\right) 
        & \left( 1-\frac{L}{n} \right)^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I diagonalized $M=SDS^{-1}$ with the eigensystem of $M$ and found

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \psi S D^n S^{-1}1
=\frac{1}{4}e^{-2L} \left(3 \cosh \left(\sqrt{2} L \right) 
+ 2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left( \sqrt{2} L \right) \right)
$$
I found this answer both by hand and by typing it into mathematica. However, when I type the original problem into mathematica, it gives
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \psi M^n 1=\frac{3}{4}e^{-2L}
$$

The latter answer is honestly more what I would have expected from the problem setup, but I don't know why the two answers differ nor how to perform the latter limit by hand. Being able to do it by hand is important, because this is actually a warm up to the bigger problem I'm working on. What am I missing? Is there good resource that could help me out, preferably in pdf form?

Edit: The eigensystem of $M$ also depends on $n$, as follows:

$$
    \lambda_1 = \left(1-\frac{L}{n}\right) \left(1-\frac{L}{n} \left(1 - \sqrt{2} \right) \right),
    \qquad
    v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
    \lambda_2 = \left(1-\frac{L}{n}\right) \left(1-\frac{L}{n} \left(1 + \sqrt{2} \right) \right),
    \qquad
    v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

giving $D=diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ and $S=[v1,v2]$.

Edit: Fixed $\sinh$ coefficient and $3/4$ coefficient.

Comment: Is $M$ a function of $n$?

Comment: Each element of $M$ contains $n$, yes. Is there something more specific you mean with the the phrase "function of $n$"?

Comment: So, you are taking the $n$th power of $M(n)$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: You have two different usages of $n.$ If you want $M$ to depend on $n,$ then write it as $M_n$ and then $M_n^n$ can't use the diagonalization of $M_1.$

Comment: Your $S$ and $D$ therefore also depends on $n$...

Comment: $D$ does depend on $n$, yes. But $S$ turned out not to. I'll add them above in an edit. @ThomasAndrews, do you have an explanation as to why not? And what to do instead?

Comment: I suspect there is a simpler recursion to get the answer, but need pen & paper to solve...

Comment: The matrices $M_n$ are all of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a&2b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}=aI+b\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ which all have the same eigenvectors, and hence same $S$ works to diagonalize all of them. The eienvalues of these matrices are $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $a-b\sqrt{2}.$ @hawkjo

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I should have made that a separate comment. I was asking about your comment. Do you have an explanation as to why $M_n^n$ can't use diagonalization?

Comment: As for why the two newest, I’m not knowledgeable about Mathematica, but then, you haven’t told us what you entered into Mathematica, so even if we did, we can’t tell whether it is your error or Mathematica’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got $$\frac{1}4e^{-2L}\left(3\cosh(L\sqrt{2})+2\sqrt{2}\sinh(L\sqrt{2})\right)$$ in two different ways.

This is close to your complicated example. I get a different coefficient for $\sinh(L\sqrt{2}).$ (Your coefficient was $\sqrt{2}.$)

In general, if $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&2b\\b&a\end{pmatrix},$ it has eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}\pm\sqrt{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $a\pm b\sqrt{2}.$ We can then write $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}4\right)\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}4\right)\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

So $$M^n 1 =\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}4\right)\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\right)^n\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}4\right)\left(a-b\sqrt{2}\right)^n\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

and hence:

$$\psi M^n 1=\left(\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\left(a-b\sqrt{2}\right)^n$$

Here, we can write $$M_n =  a_n\begin{pmatrix}a_n&2(1-a_n)\\1-a_n&a_n\end{pmatrix}$$ where $a_n=1-\frac{L}{n}.$ So $b_n=1-a_n=\frac{L}{n}.$

Then $$\psi M_n^n 1= a_n^n\left[\left(\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\left(a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\left(a_n-b_n\sqrt{2}\right)^n\right]$$

We know $a_n^n\to e^{-L}.$

And $$\left(a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}\right)^n = \left(1+\frac{L(\sqrt{2}-1)}{n}\right)^n\to e^{L(\sqrt 2-1)}$$ and $$\left(a_n-b_n\sqrt{2}\right)^n = \left(1+\frac{L(-\sqrt{2}-1)}{n}\right)^n\to e^{L(-\sqrt 2-1)}$$

So we get that:

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\left(a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\left(a_n-b_n\sqrt{2}\right)^n&\to \left(\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)e^{L(\sqrt{2}-1)}+\left(\frac{3}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)e^{L(-\sqrt{2}-1)}\\
&=e^{-L}\left(\frac{3}{4}\cosh(L\sqrt{2})+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sinh(L\sqrt{2})\right)\end{align}$$

So I get the limit is:

$$e^{-2L}\left(\frac{3}{4}\cosh(L\sqrt{2})+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sinh(L\sqrt{2})\right)$$

---

Another approach.

Note that if $a_n=1-L/n$ and $\frac{1-a_n}{a_n}=\frac{L/n}{1-L/n}=\frac{1}{n/L-1}$. Then  $$\begin{align}M_n&=a_n^2\left(I+\frac{1}{n/L-1}\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align}$$

Now, $a_n^{2n}\to e^{-2L}.$

But there is no reason to expect $$\left(I+\frac{1}{n/L-1}\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right)^n$$ to contribute nothing to this formula.

Indeed, I'd expect it to converge to $$\exp\left(L\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right)$$
3here $\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}A^k$ is the matrix exponential.
 This will be true at least when $L$ is an integer and and restricting to $n$ which are multiples of $L.$

Now, taking $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix},$ we have $A^2=2I$ and thus: $$\begin{align}\exp(LA)&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k)!}2^kL^{2K}\right)I+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}L^{2k+1}2^k\right)A\\
&=\cosh(\sqrt{2}L)I + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh(L\sqrt{2})A
\end{align}$$

Then $\psi I 1=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\psi A 1=1$ so you get the limit is:

$$e^{-2L}\left(\frac{3}{4}\cosh(L\sqrt{2})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh(L\sqrt{2}\right)$$

which is $$\frac{1}{4}e^{-2L}\left(3\cosh(L\sqrt{2})+2\sqrt{2}\sinh(L\sqrt{2})\right)$$

Comment: I end up with a $2 \sqrt{2}$ as well.

Comment: Many apologies, the original was a typo. I got $2\sqrt{2}$ as well. I fixed it with a note in the original.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The second approach here generalized to my larger problem, so was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix} $ and let
$M(x) = (1-x) (I - xA)$.

Note that $M_n = M({L \over n})$, and $A = U \begin{bmatrix} 1+\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} U^{-1}$ for some invertible $U$.

Then $M(x)^n = (1-x)^n U \begin{bmatrix} (1-x(1+\sqrt{2}))^n & 0 \\ 0 & (1-x(1-\sqrt{2}))^n \end{bmatrix} U^{-1}$.

Hence $M_n^n =(1-{L \over n})^n U \begin{bmatrix} (1-{L \over n}(1+\sqrt{2}))^n & 0 \\ 0 & (1-{L \over n}(1-\sqrt{2}))^n \end{bmatrix} U^{-1} $ from which we get
$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_n^n = e^{-L} U \begin{bmatrix} e^{-L (1+\sqrt{2})} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-L (1-\sqrt{2})} \end{bmatrix} U^{-1} = U \begin{bmatrix} e^{-L (2+\sqrt{2})} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-L (2-\sqrt{2})} \end{bmatrix} U^{-1} $.

More grind gives (making the large assumption of no mistakes):
$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_n^n = e^{-2L} \begin{bmatrix} \cosh \sqrt{2}L & \sqrt{2}  \sinh \sqrt{2}L \\
{1 \over \sqrt{2}} \sinh \sqrt{2}L & \cosh \sqrt{2}L \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I think I have made a mistake, because I end up with $\frac{1}{4}e^{-2L} \left(3 \cosh \left(\sqrt{2} L \right) 
+ 2\sqrt{2} \sinh \left( \sqrt{2} L \right) \right)$...

Comment: That is the result I got, two different ways. OP doesn't say what reduction he did to get to his $\cosh,\sinh$ formula, but I suspect it was in error.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The fact that you independently ended up with a $2 \sqrt{2}$ lends some credence...

Comment: I tried wolfram alpha in $\lim M_n^n$ when $L=1,$ and it gave the same result.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: It must be true so : -).

Comment: Many apologies, the original was a typo. I got $2\sqrt{2}$ as well. I fixed it with a note in the original.

Comment: So, on the one hand, glad you all agree with me. On the other, why does mathematica say $\lim M_n^n = e^{-2L} I$?

Comment: I don’t know Mathematica, unfortunately. I used Wolfram Alpha. @hawkjo

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I reproduced your result in WolframAlpha. I guess it's a mathematica issue, or me typing into mathematica issue. I typed Limit[{{(1 - 1/n)^2, (2 (1 - 1/n))/n}, {(1 - 1/n)/n, (1 - 1/n)^2}}^n, 
 n -> \[Infinity]] and it gave $e^{-2}I$.